# Mercurial HG Serve HTTP 500 Error

Tags: mercurial, repository, tortoisehg, tortoisehg-2.0

I'm running a mercurial repository using hg serve. I can access it via a browser and view everything in my repository however when I try to do an hg clone with the same url I get HTTP Error: 500 (Internal Server Error).

**UPDATE:** It turns out this is an issue somehow caused by using TortoiseHG web server instead of using hg serve explicitly. The error that TortoiseHG is showing is "AttributeError: 'Blackhole' object has no attribute 'fileno'"

Comment: please describe "view everything in my repository".  I've seen people say that and they were looking at a static http view of the files in their working directory, not the actual links-down-the-side application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like they're tracking this issue here: https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/937/error-cloning-repo-using-serve.

For now the solution is to run hg serve from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the output of `hg serve` command. I bet any errors will be printed right there.

If that is not enough, try passing `--errorlog somefile.log` option.

We can't help you more than this without seeing the actual error message.

Comment: is right.  Also turn on `--debug` and `--traceback`.  This is more info to whatever problem you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, and adding the extension in the .hg/hgrc of the repository itself solved the issue :

[extensions]
largefiles=